# How to call a custom method in a Rails controller from a View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller

I have set up a site that is correctly using basic CRUD functionality succesfully. However, when I try to add a custom method to my controller I cannot seem to hook it up to a `link_to` call. I keep getting a `method not found` error.

The Controller method looks like this:

```
def complete
    return render :text => "Complete"
end
```

and my call in the View looks like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Complete', complete_list_task_path(@list,@task) %>
```

This same call works for my Edit method, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Do I need to do anything special when the method is not a basic CRUD call?

The only relevant part of my route file looks like this (List and Task are nested resources. List has many tasks, and task belongs to a list):

```
resources :lists do
    resources :tasks
end
```

I have also tried adding `post "complete" => "lists/:id/tasks/:id#complete", :as => "complete"` to my route to see if it would help to implicitly try to call it, but I still got a "method not found error".

Any help in figuring out how to make this call would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's the error? Add it to the question.

Comment: please post output of `rake routes | grep complete`

Comment: I said towards the bottom that it was a "method not found error", but I have added it more prominently at the top. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Yes, do what @davidb says. If the method isn't in your routes file, it won't be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the method in the router, 'resources' refers to the 7 crud actions (index, new, create, edit, update, delete, show).

Off the top of my head, I think you'd need:

```
resources :lists do
  resources :tasks do
    member do
      post :complete
    end
  end
end
```

The nesting makes me less confident, but that's the general thing you need to do.

Comment: Quick question: how can I add 'only' to this structure? 
Like I want :tasks to have only "index" and "complete"?

Answer (score 5):

See [Adding More RESTful Actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) in the Rails Routing guide for details; the nutshell is that if you want routing to recognize anything other than the standard methods, you need to add it.